# dynamic feedback with JSF & jQuery / Javascript

Tags: forms, validation, jsf, dynamic, primefaces

We are working on a project with JSF and PrimeFaces and we are looking to add dynamic inline validation on our forms. I'm not sure if PrimeFaces can handle this (correct me if I am wrong) so I am looking for some alternatives

**Does anyone know of any plugins we could use to do this? Prefer something that incorporates JSF too...**

*I'm not a developer but a UX guy so sorry if some of the terminology is incorrect.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard JSF supports server side validation by ajax (live example [here](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/highlight)) and PrimeFaces definitely also supports it (live example [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/messages.jsf)). You can add `<f:ajax event="blur" render="message_id" />` inside input components to perform validation directly on blur (see also [this tutorial](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html#CreateJSFHelloWorldInEclipseTheView)).

```
<h:inputText id="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" required="true">
    <f:ajax event="blur" render="foo_message" />
</h:inputText>
<h:message id="foo_message" for="foo" />
```